# Initialize a logger once

Tags: c++, c++17

I am implementing a library and would like to provide just simple logging facilities without using a logging framework.

I have come to this small piece of code but it does a bit more than i expect :

```
// logging.h
#ifndef LOGGING_H 
#define LOGGING_H 

#include <iostream>

enum LogLevel {
    // no log is the default
    NoLog       = 0,
    // written to stderr
    Err         = 1,
    Warning     = 2,
    // written to stdout
    Info        = 3,
    Debug       = 4
};

void initLogger(LogLevel level);

LogLevel loggerLevel();

#define LOG(level, msg) \
    do { \
        if (level > NoLog && level <= loggerLevel()) { \
            if (level <= Warning) \
                std::cerr << __FILE__ << "(" << __LINE__ << ") " << msg << std::endl; \
            else \
                std::cout << __FILE__ << "(" << __LINE__ << ") " << msg << std::endl; \
        } \
    } while (0)
        
#define LOG_ERR(msg)    LOG(Err, msg) 
#define LOG_WARN(msg)   LOG(Warning, msg)
#define LOG_INFO(msg)   LOG(Info, msg)
#define LOG_DEBUG(msg)  LOG(Debug, msg)

#endif // LOGGING_H
```

and

```
// logging.cpp
include "logging.h"

static LogLevel logLevel = NoLog;

void initLogger(LogLevel level)
{
    logLevel = level;
}

LogLevel loggerLevel()
{
    return logLevel;
}
```

Here, the user is able to change the logging level at run-time which i don't want :

```
initLogger(Err);
    
// not printed
LOG_INFO("info");
  
initLogger(Info);
    
// printed
LOG_INFO("info");
```

I would prefer to give the user the choice to initialize the logging level once and for all or skip this step completely and fallback to a default level. I have a singleton in mind.

I guess there should be something more straightforward.
What would be the best way to achieve that ?

Thank you.

Comment: When you create a library, you want your clients to be able to be totally independent of ANY log system. You should have some callback interfaces that are called when something needs to be logged and then clients can implement their own logging adapters and inject them into your library.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Yes indeed but i would like to provide a simple default logger as well and the question is more specific on how to achieve the "init once or use default level" (though i might probably using the client logger later)

Comment: @PepijnKramer: Sometimes, for some situations you want that. Other times you have enough resource limitations that such a system isn't what you want at all--and often isn't even allowable.

Comment: Simple solution is to use a static bool in the init function. If it's already true, then just return. Otherwise, set the log level, and set the bool to true.

Comment: No do NOT provide a simple logger it is not needed. (Unless maybe it is to std::cout).

Comment: @PepijnKramer it is to `std::cout` and `std::cerr` actually.

Comment: Seems to me like the obvious answer would be to make the log level a template parameter, and use a `constexpr` if to decide whether to log something or not. With that, inactivated logging calls can be eliminated as dead code.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I do not even see too many resource issues with my approach in general.  Runtime it might be one extra indirection (which usually can be ignored when complex output is generated anyway) or an "empty call". Which doesn't need branch prediction at all.

Comment: @kzsnyk See my example you can pull in two report classes that output to std::cout and std::cerr into your library. But you leave the option open for client code to inject something completely different. And ofcourse the logger needs only initialization once  (just before injecting int)

Comment: Why do you want to prevent users from changing the log level? I'd be annoyed at a limitation like that.

Comment: @PeteBecker i want they are able to set the log level once (at run-time) but not changing it dynamically after that later in their code. It's just a design choice for now.

Comment: @JerryCoffin did not think about `constexpr` and templates, could you elaborate a little bit more on that ?

Comment: @kzsnyk -- design choices should be motivated by real-world needs. What problem does this solve?

Comment: @PeteBecker You are right, this is an arbitrary limitation and i can think of making it more flexible in the future. However, i guess this will require an additional memory protection to prevent data races when setting the log level dynamically from multiple threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With singleton, you might do:

```
static LogLevel loggerLevelInstance(LogLevel init)
{
    static const LogLevel logLevel = init; // Initialized only once

    return logLevel;
}

void initLogger(LogLevel level) { loggerLevelInstance(level); }
LogLevel loggerLevel() { return loggerLevelInstance(LogLevel::NoLog); }
```

So first call to `loggerLevelInstance` initialize for once.

Comment: `loggerLevelInstance(LogLevel::NoLog)` has an unused level parameter after the first call but it's a detail i guess

Answer (score 1):

E.g. something like this :

```
#include <string_view>
#include <iostream>

namespace your_library
{
    struct reporting_itf
    {
        virtual ~reporting_itf() = default;
        virtual void report_method_called(const std::string_view method_name) const noexcept = 0;

        // add more report options here...
        // virtual void report_internal_error() const noexcept = 0;
    };

    struct no_reporting_t : public reporting_itf
    {
        void report_method_called(const std::string_view method_name) const noexcept override {};

        //void report_internal_error() const noexcept override {};
    };

    no_reporting_t no_reporting;
    const reporting_itf* g_reporting = &no_reporting;

    void set_reporting(const reporting_itf& reporting)
    {
        g_reporting = &reporting;
    }

    void some_function()
    {
        g_reporting->report_method_called(__FUNCTION__);
    }

}


namespace client_code
{
    struct client_logger_t : public your_library::reporting_itf
    {
        void report_method_called(const std::string_view method_name) const noexcept override
        {
            std::cout << "called : " << method_name << "\n";
            // should be something like LOG(Informational....)
        };

        // Internal logger classes
        // Logger m_log;
    };
}


int main()
{
    client_code::client_logger_t client_logger; 
    your_library::set_reporting(client_logger);

    your_library::some_function();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version using a template and `if constexpr` expressions, so a logger can only be initialized with a specific level one time, and logging to a level that's disabled should result in no code being generated for that call at all.

```cpp
// logging.h
#ifndef LOGGING_H 
#define LOGGING_H 

#include <iostream>

enum LogLevel {
    // no log is the default
    NoLog       = 0,
    // written to stderr
    Err         = 1,
    Warning     = 2,
    // written to stdout
    Info        = 3,
    Debug       = 4
};

template <int currentLevel, int logLevel>
class Logger {
public:
    static void write(char const *file, int line, char const *msg) {
        if constexpr (logLevel > currentLevel)
            return;

        if constexpr (logLevel <= Warning)
            std::cerr << file << "(" << line << ") " << msg << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << file << "(" << line << ") " << msg << std::endl;
    }    
};


#define initLogging(level)                  \
    using ErrLog = Logger<level, Err>;      \
    using WarnLog = Logger<level, Warning>; \
    using InfoLog = Logger<level, Info>;    \
    using DebugLog = Logger<level, Debug>;

#define LOG_ERR(msg)    ErrLog::write(__FILE__, __LINE__, msg) 
#define LOG_WARN(msg)   WarnLog::write(__FILE__, __LINE__, msg)
#define LOG_INFO(msg)   InfoLog::write(__FILE__, __LINE__, msg)
#define LOG_DEBUG(msg)  DebugLog::write(__FILE__, __LINE__, msg)

#endif // LOGGING_H
```

Here's a quick demo:

```cpp
#include "logging.hpp"

initLogging(Warning);

int main() {
    LOG_ERR("Error Message");
    LOG_WARN("Warning Message");
    LOG_INFO("Info Message");
    LOG_DEBUG("Debug Message");
}
```

At least as the code currently stands, the use of `initLogging` is required, not optional (and as shown, it should normally be at global scope, not inside a function).

Doing a quick check on Godbolt, it appears that calls to disabled logging levels are optimized out completely (at least in a simple situation like the test program):

https://godbolt.org/z/G57E5xhs6

One point though: just like almost anything else the `Logger` objects do observe scope. As such, you can create different levels of logging in different scopes if you really want to, and the objects in each scope will observe the level they were initialized to in that scope. For example:

```cpp
#include "logging.hpp"

initLogging(Warning);

void breaklevel() { 

    // in this scope, logging will happen at debug level:
    initLogging(Debug);

    // so *all* of these will print:
    LOG_ERR("Error Message");
    LOG_WARN("Warning Message");
    LOG_INFO("Info Message");
    LOG_DEBUG("Debug Message");
}

int main() {

    // but these use the global logger, so only the error and
    // warning messages will print:

    LOG_ERR("Error Message");
    LOG_WARN("Warning Message");
    LOG_INFO("Info Message");
    LOG_DEBUG("Debug Message");
    breaklevel();
}
```

Each logger is only initialized once, but since they observe scope, each scope can have its own logger objects...

Comment: Very interesting even if it's actually more than i asked with the scoped logger, it points to a new direction. However i don't see any difference between the generated assembly with and without `constexpr`  on godbolt.

Comment: @kzsnyk: In a program that's small/simple enough for the optimizer to have full visibility into the logging level being a constant, so it can always detect the dead code of a logging call that won't produce any output, I wouldn't expect any difference. Using `constexpr` assures that it remains detectable as dead code, regardless of the size or complexity of program involved.